# Determinant of $(K-\lambda M)$ is NOT zero for an eigenvalue!

Tags: linear-algebra

For an eigenvalue problem, it is expected to get $\det(K-\lambda M)=0$ for $\lambda = {}$eigenvalue. However while working on a vibration problem, I got $8\times8$ stiffness ($K$) and mass ($M$) matrices and had an eigenvalue/eigenvector solution by using scipy.linalg.eig(K, M) in Python.

To be able to solve this problem in excel, I constructed the same matrices and did the math for a new matrix such as $K - \lambda M$ and calculate $\det(K - \lambda M).$ When I inserted an eigenvalue for lambda, I realized that determinant is in the order of $10\times10^{57}$ instead of $0.$

I searched for textbooks but everywhere I see that $\det(K - \lambda M)$ should be $0$ for an eigenvalue solution.

I wanted to get some opinions on the subject in case I have a missing knowledge.

Best regards.

Comment: You sure it is 1e57 (i.e $10^{57}$) and not 1e-57, i.e. $10^{-57}$?

Comment: Also, what does python compute when you calculate $\det(K-\lambda M)$?

Comment: I checked myself a couple of times and it is 1e57. Python also computes the same answer.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but of what matrix is $\lambda$ supposed to be an eigenvalue?

Comment: My matrices are;

Comment: M: [2881,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0
0,0 31,2 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0
0,0 0,0 17,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0
0,0 0,0 0,0 17,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0
0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 4,8 0,0 0,0 0,0
0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 131,4 0,0 0,0
0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 577,0 0,0
0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 13046,0]

Comment: K = [76860000,0 -76860000,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0
-76860000,0 114480000,0 -37620000,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0
0,0 -37620000,0 75240000,0 -37620000,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0
0,0 0,0 -37620000,0 101000000,0 -63380000,0 0,0 0,0 0,0
0,0 0,0 0,0 -63380000,0 205580000,0 -142200000,0 0,0 0,0
0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -142200000,0 204650000,0 -62450000,0 0,0
0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -62450000,0 64700000,0 -2250000,0
0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -2250000,0 2250000,0]

Comment: I get you are using a convention where comma separates the integer part from decimals, like $0,1=\frac1{10}$ instead of the Anglo-Saxon $0.1$?

Comment: Yes, comma separates the integer from decimals. Excuse me for the mess, I copied it from excel sheet.

Comment: $5.33850837e+07+0.j, 7.20477109e+06+0.j, 4.15918067e+06+0.j,
        1.78563183e+06+0.j, 5.72215972e+05+0.j, 2.01676776e+04+0.j,
        6.79173779e+02+0.j, 1.17571546e-12+0.j$
These are the eigenvalues. Which one are you using?

Comment: If I use 6.79173779+02 as lambda, I get 1,95209E+56 for  det(−)

Answer (score 2):

Eigevalues of $K$ are solution of

$$
\det(K -\lambda I) =0 \tag{1}
$$

Generalized eigevalues of the pair $K, M$ are solutions of

$$
\det(K -\lambda M) =0  \tag{2}
$$

Besides, since/when  $M$ is positive, these are also solution of

$$
\det(M^{-1/2}K M^{-1/2} -\lambda I)=0   \tag{3}
$$

I.e. the problem is brought back to a standard eigenvalue problem for a different matrix (but this is another story).

Comment: I get your point. I also tried to get an answer by using third equation, which should be a zero, but unfortunately it is also not zero.

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't call eigevalues solution of (2), rather generalized eigevalues. If you plug a solution of (1) into (2) you won't get zero.

Comment: Otherwise if you really mean you computed solution of (2) and then plug them back into the left hand side of (2) and didn't get zero, well then there's a bug or something.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. What I am doing is exactly this: I am finding eigenvalues for (2) by using scipy.linalg.eig(K, M). This is a solution for K x =   x. Then I am inserting eigenvalues from this solution to Eq. (2). The matrices are given under my first post and as an example, I get det(−) = 1,95209E+56 with  = 6.79173779+02. My expectation is to get a zero. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes you should get zero, there must be a bug/typo. You are kind of saying "I find solutions of (2) which are not solutions of (2)".

Comment: I understand. As I mentioned, I solved it by Python then tried these solutions in both excel and Python (in Eq. (2)) and I am getting the same results which everybody (including me) thinks that it is wrong. This is why I brought the subject here, to discuss if there is something in the theory that I am missing.

Comment: I understand. When you're debugging sometime you feel the rule of the universe have suddenly changed. Keep searching you'll find the bug! I'd suggest try to get the generalized eigevalues in wolphram alpha and see if they match your python script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109318/discussion-between-burak-and-lcv).